# How to ensure Winforms controls stay right-aligned regardless of font setting?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms application written in c#. I create checkboxes, textboxes and buttons in a panel. I have some problems when I run it in the rectangle monitor.

If I make the computer font size normal (control panel -> Appearance and Themes), there is no problem. Textbox and button alignment is top right and it works.

But when I change the computer font to larger from control panel textboxes and buttons go left. Alignments don't work. By the way I created all in run time. I use this code:

```
tmin[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
tmax[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
gb[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
```

tmin and tmax are arrays of textboxes. gb is array of button. what can I do about this?

EDIT

For example initiliazation of tmax textbox array is :

```
 height = 1;
 padding = 10;

 for (int i = 3; i < ff.documentColumnCount; i++)
 {                
   tmax[i] = new TextBox();
   tmax[i].Name = max + (i - 2).ToString();
   tmax[i].TabIndex = i;
   tmax[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(65, 20);
   tmax[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(326, 36 + i * 20);
   tmax[i].TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(tmax17_TextChanged);
   tmax[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(326, 20 + padding + height, 65, 22);
   tmax[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
   maxTextBoxes.Add(tmax[i]);
   panel5.Controls.Add(tmax[i]);
   height += 22;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to set their Location property correctly before turning on the Anchor.

Comment: I have already done like that. I will write one of them whole initiliazation. Others already are similar with it. See edit

Answer (score 1):

Don't use anchors. Using Dock property instead, and set Min size as needed.

Comment: I don't see how using the `Dock` property will do any better than using an anchor.

Comment: Did you try it, or are you just guessing that it won't make a difference?

Comment: Docking only works against the **edges** of the form, and doesn't allow you to have padding or spaces between controls.  From the description and code in the question, I don't see how docking would solve the OP's problem.  If you could expand your answer and explain how it would solve the OP's problem, I'd be happy to change my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of anchoring the control to the right edge of the form (which is what `AnchorStyles.Right` means), set the [`TextAlign` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.textalign.aspx) to `HorizontalAlignment.Right`, so that the *text within the control* is right-aligned.