# How do I place the button besides the tab?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

[image]

I have this C# winform with tabs on toolstrip. I need to place that plus button on extreme right "+" besides the latest tab on toolstrip. I have tried for location, but couldn't get it. Is there any other way to do this. The button should shift its position based on the new tab added or deleted

Comment: How do you place the Tabs on a ToolStrip? Also : _The button should shift its position_ So it should not always stay to the right??

Comment: Have you taken a closer look at these answers?
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672412/how-to-ensure-winforms-controls-stay-right-aligned-regardless-of-font-setting>

Comment: Currently the button is in fixed position. I need the button to be besides the tab "PriceWatch". If any of the 3 tabs is deleted then the button should shift its position accordingly.

Comment: @TaW He has the tabcontrol on top of the toolstrip but only the tabs are visible. The rest of the tabcontrol is out of the form(if dock is bottom) or the height is exactly the tabs height. You can see it in the image. The line from the third tab goes along the toolstrip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses a workaround: It **owner-draws** the `Tab` control in order to get the `Bounds` of each Tab..:

[image]

```
private void tabControl_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var page = tabControl.TabPages[e.Index];
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, page.Text, page.Font, e.Bounds, e.ForeColor);

    if (e.Index == tabControl.TabCount - 1)
        button6.Left = tabControl.Left + e.Bounds.Right + 3;
}

private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl.TabPages.Add("new page " + tabControl.TabCount);
}
private void buttonRemoveLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt(tabControl.TabCount - 1);
}
```

You may want to change the owner-drawing to suit your application.. There a are quite a few examples around.